# I would like to add effect my pointer. How to add effect or animation to touched area?

Tags: android, animation, scroll, touch, effect

I would like to add effects to my pointer. That is, while I am scrolling my finger in screen, show up effect or animation around which is showed up touched area. how to add?

Comment: so, what are you trying todo? Add a imageview below the users finger and spin it around with an animation as long as he touches the screen?

Comment: What is your particular problem? Did you ever try something by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new DrawingView(this));
}

class DrawingView extends SurfaceView {

    private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 50, paint);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: this looks useful, i am just trying to add my codeblocks. thanks my friend.

Comment: Caner, i already use 
@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
  if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
   return true; 
  else
  return false;
  
 }
because of i use this class;

class detectorClass extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener

Comment: i want use onscroll or onfling function and ur code must be compatible with my on scroll or on fling code.

Comment: that is, instead of MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
require MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, 
yet it isn't working..